# How to apply topographic hillshading/relief to a filled contour plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot of some gridded data, with topographic relief shading based on some underlying elevation data.

Most of the examples I can find in the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/specialty_plots/topographic_hillshading.html)  only show to to shade the elevation data itself - not how to shade some separate array based on elevation.

I was able to come up with the following code which *almost* does what I want it to do. I first create a "dummy" image to generate an RGBA array with, and then pass that RGBA array to the
LightSource.shade_rgb() function.

```
#load elevation data
dem = get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', np_load=True)
z   = dem['elevation']

#make a grid to plot over elevation
x = np.arange(z.shape[1])
y = np.arange(z.shape[0])
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x,y)
data = x_grid + y_grid

#make a dummy plot to extract rgba information from
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)
plt.close(fig)

#extract RGBA array from dummy image
rgba = np.reshape(im.to_rgba(data.ravel()), data.shape + (4,))

#apply relief shading
ls = LightSource(azdeg=315, altdeg=45)
data_hillshade = ls.shade_rgb(rgba, z, blend_mode = 'soft', vert_exag = 0.5)

#plot hillshaded data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data_hillshade)
```

[image]

However, what I really want is a *filled contour plot* (i.e. contourf) with hillshading.

If I try a similar method, but use `contourf` to create the dummy plot instead of imshow...

```
#load elevation data
dem = get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', np_load=True)
z   = dem['elevation']

#make a grid to plot over elevation
x = np.arange(z.shape[1])
y = np.arange(z.shape[0])
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x,y)
data = x_grid + y_grid

#make a dummy plot to extract rgba information from
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.contourf(data)
plt.close(fig)

#extract RGBA array from dummy image
rgba = np.reshape(im.to_rgba(data.ravel()), data.shape + (4,))

#apply relief shading
ls = LightSource(azdeg=315, altdeg=45)
data_hillshade = ls.shade_rgb(rgba, z, blend_mode = 'soft', vert_exag = 0.5)

#plot hillshaded data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data_hillshade)
```

...I just end up with the same plot as before, with no contour lines. The `to_rgba()` function I am using to convert the image to an RGBA array apparently does not conserve the "contoury-ness" of the image.

Is there any way to get a hillshaded contour plot with matplotlib? Essentially, I would like to have the image above, but with several distinct contour colors, rather than a smooth gradation of colors.

EDIT:
I came up with a solution below, but I'm leaving this as an open question because it still doesn't do exactly what I want. As can be seen in the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#discrete-bounds), using the Discrete bounds normalization with `pcolormesh` leaves the plot with a "gridded" appearance - it does not quite have the smooth contour lines the `contourf` gives you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by incorporating the [`BoundaryNorm` normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#discrete-bounds) function to make a pcolormesh plot look like a contour plot.

```
#load elevation data
dem = get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', np_load=True)
z   = dem['elevation']

#make a grid to plot over elevation
x = np.arange(z.shape[1])
y = np.arange(z.shape[0])
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x,y)
data = x_grid + y_grid

bounds = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 10)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=256)

#make a dummy plot to extract rgba information from
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolormesh(data, norm=norm)
plt.close(fig)

#extract RGBA array from dummy image
rgba = np.reshape(im.to_rgba(data.ravel()), data.shape + (4,))

#apply relief shading
ls = LightSource(azdeg=315, altdeg=45)
data_hillshade = ls.shade_rgb(rgba, z, blend_mode = 'soft', vert_exag = 0.5)

#plot hillshaded data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data_hillshade)
```

[image]

EDIT: This is not a perfect solution, because it results in a "gridded"-looking plot, and does not give the smooth contour lines that `contourf` gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me thank you so much for updating your solution !
Adding interpolation in the plot makes it smoother, not sure if that's what you want though:

ax.imshow(data_hillshade,interpolation='bilinear')

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. Maybe it is better as a comment?